# error loading model: MapViewOfFile failed: Not enough memory resources are available to process this command

Tags: llama, llamacpp

PC specs: ryzen 5700x,32gb ram, 100gb free space sdd, rtx 3060 12gb vram

I'm trying to run locally llama-7b-chat model. Followed every instruction step, first converted the model to ggml FP16 format

`python convert.py .\models\llama-2-7b-chat\`

then

`./quantize .\models\llama-2-7b-chat\ggml-model-f16.gguf .\models\llama-2-7b-chat\ggml-model-q4_0.bin q4_0`

now when i run with

`.\main -m .\models\llama-2-7b-chat\ggml-model-q4_0.gguf -n 512`

it gives me this error

`

```
main: build = 1019 (ef3f333)
main: seed  = 1692713716
llama_model_loader: loaded meta data with 15 key-value pairs and 291 tensors from .\models\llama-2-7b-chat\ggml-model-q4_0.gguf (version GGUF V1 (latest))

// skipped this part

llama_model_loader: - kv   0:                       general.architecture str
llama_model_loader: - kv   1:                               general.name str
llama_model_loader: - kv   2:                       llama.context_length u32
llama_model_loader: - kv   3:                     llama.embedding_length u32
llama_model_loader: - kv   4:                          llama.block_count u32
llama_model_loader: - kv   5:                  llama.feed_forward_length u32
llama_model_loader: - kv   6:                 llama.rope.dimension_count u32
llama_model_loader: - kv   7:                 llama.attention.head_count u32
llama_model_loader: - kv   8:              llama.attention.head_count_kv u32
llama_model_loader: - kv   9:     llama.attention.layer_norm_rms_epsilon f32
llama_model_loader: - kv  10:                       tokenizer.ggml.model str
llama_model_loader: - kv  11:                      tokenizer.ggml.tokens arr
llama_model_loader: - kv  12:                      tokenizer.ggml.scores arr
llama_model_loader: - kv  13:                  tokenizer.ggml.token_type arr
llama_model_loader: - kv  14:               general.quantization_version u32
llama_model_loader: - type  f32:   65 tensors
llama_model_loader: - type q4_0:  225 tensors
llama_model_loader: - type q6_K:    1 tensors
llama_model_load_internal: format       = GGUF V1 (latest)
llama_model_load_internal: arch         = llama
llama_model_load_internal: vocab type   = SPM
llama_model_load_internal: n_vocab      = 32000
llama_model_load_internal: n_ctx_train  = 2048
llama_model_load_internal: n_ctx        = 512
llama_model_load_internal: n_embd       = 4096
llama_model_load_internal: n_head       = 32
llama_model_load_internal: n_head_kv    = 32
llama_model_load_internal: n_layer      = 32
llama_model_load_internal: n_rot        = 128
llama_model_load_internal: n_gqa        = 1
llama_model_load_internal: f_norm_eps   = 1.0e-06
llama_model_load_internal: n_ff         = 11008
llama_model_load_internal: freq_base    = 10000.0
llama_model_load_internal: freq_scale   = 1
llama_model_load_internal: model type   = 7B
llama_model_load_internal: model ftype  = mostly Q4_0
llama_model_load_internal: model size   = 6.74 B
llama_model_load_internal: general.name = LLaMA
llama_model_load_internal: BOS token = 1 '<s>'
llama_model_load_internal: EOS token = 2 '</s>'
llama_model_load_internal: LF token  = 13 '<0x0A>'
llama_model_load_internal: ggml ctx size =    0.07 MB
llama_model_load_internal: mem required  = 3647.94 MB (+  256.00 MB per state)
error loading model: MapViewOfFile failed: Not enough memory resources are available to process this command.

llama_load_model_from_file: failed to load model
llama_init_from_gpt_params: error: failed to load model '.\models\llama-2-7b-chat\ggml-model-q4_0.gguf'
main: error: unable to load model
```

`

I tried changing the context length and also redoing every step. Didnt help